# How to calculate %-difference between todays and yesterdays values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
id   _date          timestamp       views   change
--------------------------------------------------
1   2011-01-31  1296514800  550        0.00
1   2011-02-01  1296601200  504       -8.36
1   2011-02-02  1296687600  484       -3.97
2   2011-01-31  1296514800   50        0.00
2   2011-02-01  1296601200   40      -20.00
2   2011-02-02  1296687600   45       12.50
3   2011-01-31  1296514800  150        0.00
3   2011-02-01  1296601200  180       20.00
3   2011-02-02  1296687600  200       11.11
```

Notice that the table is first ordered by `id` and then by `_date`. I have the same number of `_date`s for each `id`.

In the `change` column, I would like to calculate the %-difference in views between yesterday and today for each company `id`. Please notice that whenever we start calculating the %change for a new company `id`, the first row should say `0.00` since we have no yesterdays value to calculate with. The other values are simply calculated with folmula:

```
todays_value - yesterdays_value          504 - 550
------------------------------- x 100 =  --------- x 100 = -8.36
       yesterdays_value                     550
```

My question is: can this be done in MySQL and if so, how, or should I use a PHP layer (preferably not :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in SQL. One way to do it is using user-defined variables to track the values from one row to the next. In order to get your desired output you can do the calculation in a sub-query and then omit the columns that track the previous row values from the final output.

Try something like this:

```
select id, _date, views, change_pct
from 
(
  select @id := id as id, _date as _date, @views := views as views, 
    (case when @id = @last_id then round(((@views - @last_views)/@last_views)*100,2) else 0.00 end) as change_pct,
    @last_id := @id, @last_views := @views
  from your_table
  order by id,_date
) as sub_query
order by id,_date;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "is this possible in MySQL". I believe you have given a SQL (non-MySQL compatible) solution?

Comment: My answer will work in MySQL. My point is that you can do this in SQL (as opposed to PHP) since that was your preference, but I did notice you asked specifically about MySQL and this query will work with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note on line4, date as _date instead of _date as _date.